# How automatically create button in windows form?

Tags: winforms, powershell

I'm a "noobie" in scripting (ok, I'm particully a noob with windows form...) and I actually try to create a powershell function to "dynamically" generate a form.

I wish like, for exemple, I could write :

```
MyFunction -ButtonList "Button1,Button2,Button3"
```

And obtain this :
[Result Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U3sm.png)

And when I click on a button I want to get button name (totaly useless, yes, but it's a training.)

My problem is I don't know how automaticaly generate buttons... I try this :

```
$i=0
foreach($Button in $ButtonList)
    {
    $CurrentButton = $null

    $CurrentButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $CurrentButton.Location = "125,$(100+50*$i)"
    $CurrentButton.size = '250,35'
    $CurrentButton.Text = $Button
    $CurrentButton.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font ($Police,$ButtonSize,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
    $CurrentButton.add_click({$Script:Result = $CurrentButton.Text ;$form.Close()})
    $form.Controls.Add($CurrentButton)
    $i++
    }
```

But whatever which button a select, I alway get same result = name of last button create ("Button3" in this exemple)

I suppose problem come from  `$CurrentButton.add_click({$Script:Result = $CurrentButton.Text ;$form.Close()})` But I don't know how fix it...

thank you in advance for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$this.Text` instead of `$CurrentButton.Text`.
The variable `$CurrentButton` is unknown in the click handler.
There you can use the automatic variable `$this` that is a reference to the button control object itself.

Comment: I didn't know this automatic variable.

Thank a lots !

Comment: @Mira Glad to have helped. If you feel my answer solved your problem, please mark it by clicking the checkmark icon to the left.